# The maximum number of vertical independent vector fields on the tangent bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, terminology, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold.

Is there a name for the maximum number of globally defined independent vector  fields on $TM$ which are tangent to the fibers of $TM\to M$? Is there a name for the maximum number of globally defined independent vector fields on $TM$ which are tangent to the fibers of $TM\to M$ and whose mutual flows commute, i.e. they are vertical and have pairwise zero Lie bracket? What kind of characteristic classes can be used to compute such quantities? What are these maximum numbers for $M = S^n$?

**Edit:(After the answer by Michael Albanese)**

The vertical rank of  $TM$ is the maximum number of  independent commuting vertical vector fields on $TM$. the rank of $M$ is the maximum number of  independent commuting vector fields on $M$?[This terminology coined by Milnor](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970383?seq=1)

> Question: Is the vertical rank of $TM$  equal to the rank of $M$?

Comment: A vector bundle has $k$ independent vector fields iff its classifying map lifts from $BO(n)$ to $BO(n-k)$. In your case, this is the composition of the classifying map of $TM$ with the projection to $M$, which is a homotopy equivalence. For spheres, this is known explicitly, cf   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_on_spheres Integrable distributions can probably also be described explicitly using Haefliger's theorem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will address the first version of your question (i.e. no conditions on commuting flows).

A vector bundle $E \to B$ admits $k$ linearly independent vector fields if and only if $E$ has a subbundle isomorphic to $\varepsilon^k$, the trivial rank $k$ bundle. The largest such $k$ is called the *span* of $E$. If $E$ has rank $n$ with span $k$, then $w_i(E) = 0$ for $i > n - k$ and $p_i(E) = 0$ for $i > \lfloor\frac{1}{2}(n-k)\rfloor$.

If $\pi : TM \to M$ denotes the natural projection, then the subbundle of $TTM$ consisting of vectors tangent to the fibers of $\pi$ is precisely $\ker(d\pi)$. Your first question can be rephrased as: what is the span of $\ker(d\pi)$? Note that $\ker(d\pi) \cong \pi^*TM$, and hence $\operatorname{span}(\ker(d\pi)) = \operatorname{span}(\pi^*TM)$. In general, $\operatorname{span}(f^*E) \geq \operatorname{span}(E)$ but in our case, $\pi : TM \to M$ is a homotopy equivalence, so we obtain $\operatorname{span}(\pi^*TM) = \operatorname{span}(TM)$ which we often call the span of $M$.

The span of a manifold is very difficult to calculate in general. For spheres, the problem was resolved by Adams in 1962 - note, the characteristic class conditions mentioned above tell us nothing here as spheres are stably parallelisable. The span of $S^{n-1}$ is $\rho(n) - 1$ where $\rho(n)$ denotes the $n^{\text{th}}$ Radon-Hurwitz number, defined as follows: if $n = 2^{4a + b}c$ where $a, b, c$ are non-negative integers, $0 \leq b \leq 3$ and $c$ is odd, then $\rho(n) = 8a + 2^b$.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer. To be honest i was aware of isomorphicity of  a vertical space at $V_p$ with $T_p M$ but I did not pay attention to the equivalent global formulation you mentioned: The subbundle of vertical tangent vectors is isomorphic to the pull back bundle $\pi^* TM$. So by your very  argument we realize that if we have $k$ commuting independent vector fields on $M$ then we have $k$ commuting independent vertical vector field on $TM$. So the vertical rank of TM is $\geq$ than the rank of $M$.,

Comment: By rank of  $M$, I mean the maximum number of  commuting independent vector fields. a terminology coined by, i think Milnor. So can one say that the vertical rank of TM is always equal to rank of M?

Comment: A more explanation of my previuos 2 comments. let $V_p$ is given. We define a linear isomorphism from $T_p M$ to vertical vectors in $T_{V_p} TM$ with $X\mapsto d/dt V_p+tX\mid_{t=0}$. But this map preserves the Lie bracket, so commuting vector fields would be lifted tocommuting vector fields. Am I right?

Comment: But I guess you some thing is missing in your notations when you write:$d\pi:\ker d\pi \to TM$ is  an isomorphism", right?

Comment: Thanks  again for your very interesting argument, very helpful information in the last paragraph and your helpful statement $\pi^* TM \simeq \ker d\pi$.

Comment: What I wrote about $d\pi$ was clearly wrong, I removed that. Thanks for pointing it out. I will be away from my computer for a while, but I will think about the rank question.

Comment: I just realized that may be the vertical rank of  $TM$ is may be equal to span of $TM$ because if we have k independent vector fields $X_1.X_2,\ldots,X_m$ on $M$ we lift them to k independent vertical vector  fields $\tilde{X}_1,\ldots,\tilde{X}_k$ on $TM$ but each lifted vector field is  a  "constant" vector  field on the fiber. So we automatically have $[\tilde{X}_i, \tilde{X}_j]=0$. Am I right? But if we pose the same question in the case of principale bundles or vector bundles, rather than $TM \to M$ we possibly get non trivial question.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: The lifts aren't canonical, but for any such lifts we have $d\pi[\tilde{X}_i, \tilde{X}_j] = [d\pi(\tilde{X}_i), d\pi(\tilde{X}_j)] = [X_i, X_j] = 0$ so $[\tilde{X}_i, \tilde{X}_j]$ is a vertical vector field, but it's not clear to me that you can choose the lifts so that the Lie bracket is zero.

Comment: I think the lift is  a canonical lift and is  coordinate free:Let $V_p\in TM$ is a point in the total space. Then the lift has the following formula:$X\in T_p M\mapsto d/dt(V_p+tX)\mid_{t=0}$. But each fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is  a linear space:Compare this construction at $V_p$ and $W_p$. I think the lifted vector field  restricts to a  contstant vector field on each fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$.(The term constant vector field is  a  legal term in a vector space, i.e a fiber).  so this canonical lifing has  range in a very particular Lie  subalgebra of $\chi^{\infty}(TM)$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: You're right, you do get canonical lifts that way.

Comment: Thank you again for your attention to my question and your interesting answer.